# Saving a nested prefab via script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For context, I'm using Unity 2019.4.40 so a few of the PrefabUtility changes are not available to me.  With that out of the way:

Setup: I have a component `SpriteList` that lives on a prefab `SpritesPrefab`.  The prefab has an instance that is nested within another prefab `ParentPrefab`, and that `ParentPrefab` is placed in the scene. This `SpriteList` component also has an array `List<Sprite> items` on it.

Usage:  I have created a custom editor unrelated to the prefab and component in question.  It searches the open scene for a `SpriteList` component and calls a public method on `SpriteList` which simply adds an item to the `items` array via `items.Add(mySprite)`. It then attempts to apply those changes to `SpritesPrefab`, not to `ParentPrefab`, where I would hope they should still show up as overrides.  It is this last part I am failing to do.

I'll go ahead and say I have tried a lot of things and can't recount them all because my understanding of `PrefabUtility` is spotty at best and the documentation confuses me.  However, I will share below the current state (which doesn't work) and a previous state that also didn't work.  All of this code lives on `SpriteList` in a public method intended for adding sprites.

Attempt 1: This attempt seems to work when `SpritePrefab` is not nested in `ParentPrefab` in the scene, but if it's nested it totally writes something quite broken to `SpritePrefab`.  Specifically, it:

1. Makes `ParentPrefab` become overriden by a new `SpritePrefab` that lacks the `SpriteList` component
2. Makes what used to be `ParentPrefab` become nested within `SpritePrefab` and seen as `Missing Prefab` by unity.
3. Within `ParentPrefab` is a non-prefab object that is identical to what `SpritePrefab` was but is not connected to any prefab.
   Sounds confusing but it's not super important to understand, other than, it doesn't work.

```
items.Add(mySprite);
PrefabUtility.RecordPrefabInstancePropertyModifications(gameObject);
EditorUtility.SetDirty(gameObject);
GameObject prefabObj = PrefabUtility.GetNearestPrefabInstanceRoot(gameObject);
GameObject prefabRoot = PrefabUtility.GetOutermostPrefabInstanceRoot(prefabObj);
string prefabPath = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabAssetPathOfNearestInstanceRoot(prefabObj);
PrefabUtility.ApplyPrefabInstance(prefabObj, InteractionMode.AutomatedAction);
PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAssetAndConnect(prefabRoot, prefabPath, InteractionMode.AutomatedAction);
```

Attempt 2:  This seems to fail to write to disk at times and work at other times, but it's unclear exactly what causes this.  It also saves all dirty assets, which I would like to avoid because there's some scene assets that are always dirty and make the procedure take longer as a result.

```
AssetDatabase.StartAssetEditing();
items.Add(mySprite);
PrefabUtility.ApplyPrefabInstance(gameObject, InteractionMode.AutomatedAction);
AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
AssetDatabase.StopAssetEditing();
```

I've tried a few other things too but it was more like google --> trial --> error situation so I can't reproduce all my attempts.

Anyway, any insight on how to accomplish the goal of having a component that lives on a nested prefab instance, modifies its own values, then applies those modifications and saves to the nested prefab's asset, and not the parent prefab would be appreciated!

For clarification, the effect I'm trying to get is the identical effect as if I changed the nested prefab instance and then clicked `Apply Overrides To Nested prefab` and **not** `Apply Overrides to Parent Prefab`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to modify Hunter Barclay's approach to work directly on the nested prefab and ignore the parent like so:

```
// Get the path of the SpriteList prefab
// we're using GetPrefabAssetPathOfNearestInstanceRoot()
// since the SpriteList prefab may be nested in another prefab
string prefabPath = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabAssetPathOfNearestInstanceRoot(gameObject);

// Loads the prefab into memory in an isolated way.  
// We must load the prefab this way and work on this
// loaded object for changes to be saved to the prefab.
// Otherwise, changes are made to the prefab instance and not the
// prefab itself, and are instead applied as overrides to any
// parent prefabs it might be nested within.
GameObject prefabAsset = PrefabUtility.LoadPrefabContents(prefabPath);

// Modify the prefab, and save it, even though this code is in
// the SpriteList component, we still have to retrieve the one
// on prefabAsset, the current one is on the prefab instance
prefabAsset.GetComponent<SpriteList>().items.Add(mySprite);
PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(prefabAsset, prefabPath);

// Unload the prefab.
PrefabUtility.UnloadPrefabContents(prefabAsset);
```

This takes the nested prefab instance (gameObject, the script is attached to it), and finds the path to its prefab asset.  Then we load the prefab asset in memory and do the modifications on the prefab asset itself.  We save and unload it.

This approach works whether or not the `SpritesPrefab` is nested in another `ParentPrefab` instance, or is just directly in the scene unnested.

Answer (score 0):

I made a test situation where I have a parent prefab called `Parent` and a child prefab called `Storage`. The child prefab contains a component called `StorageList` that stores a list of strings. I was able to adapt the example found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.LoadPrefabContents.html). In this editor script, it loads the parent prefab into an isolated scene, then modifies the child prefab similarly to how you did. It then unloads the parent prefab, achieving the effect you wanted. You can expand this to go into children of child prefabs if you wanted:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class Example {

    private const string PARENT_PREFAB_PATH = "Assets/Parent.prefab";

    [MenuItem("Examples/Storage Test")]
    static void StorageTest() {
        // Loads outer prefab into isolated scene
        GameObject contentsRoot = PrefabUtility.LoadPrefabContents(PARENT_PREFAB_PATH);

        // Modifys inner prefab and saves it
        GameObject storage = contentsRoot.transform.Find("Storage").gameObject;
        storage.GetComponent<StorageList>().Items.Add("Test");
        PrefabUtility.ApplyPrefabInstance(storage, InteractionMode.AutomatedAction);

        // Unload the parent prefab.
        PrefabUtility.UnloadPrefabContents(contentsRoot);
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like from your description that this will change the parent prefab asset, which I don't want to do.  Or rather, I don't want the changes to be saved as overrides of the Parent prefab.  I want to change the nested prefab instance and save it to the nested prefab asset.  Am I interpreting that correctly?

Comment: You're right, I just did a quick test and removing the save from the parent prefab and just unloading it actually has the exact same affect. I edited my answer accordingly. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: I tried this and it still seems to modify the parent prefab only, so that the changes persist as overrides in the parent prefab.  It might be that there's an additional piece needed after ApplyPrefabInstance() so that the changes are written to disk, but im not sure.  I'm not sure if when you tried it you were already in the prefab editing environment, but I'm running this from the scene view.

Comment: I should add that my setup is a bit different from yours - for me, the code you have above that does the adding and Prefabutility functions lives inside what you're calling the StorageList component, and it needs to be there.  I'm not sure if that makes a difference, it looks like what you are writing is an editor tool, so it might.  The only thing my custom editor does is call StorageList.AddSprite(sprite) which then contains all the code above

Comment: I was able to modify your method to work directly on the nested prefab.  It turns out if I isolate the nested prefab instead of the parent prefab using the method you suggest it works.   If you want to modify your answer, I would love to accept yours since my solution was inspired by it.  I posted my solution as an answer since it won't fit in the comments but if you modify yours I'll accepts yours instead

Comment: Ah well since I haven't seen you reply, i went ahead and accepted my answer.  Thanks for helping me find it anyway!